# Understanding the rails relationship between "require" and class naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, scope

As far as I understand, in Rails you don't have to require most of the files that you use, and that most of these files are auto-magically required or included in your code as you reference appropriate classes.

If I understand If I do the following in some arbitrary file, or via running a script with `rails runner myscript.rb`

**myscript.rb**

```
User.delete_all
#set up a default user
User.create(name: "default", password: "default")
```

This file automatically sees a class it doesnt recognize, `User`, and understands via its naming convention that the class must be defined in /app/models/user.rb then this code is somehow made available via require or something similar.

My question is: How does rails implement this feature? This is something I'd very much like to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends a lot on the environment. In production, everything is loaded at boot time and all the classes are cached. In development, the classes are found with [`const_missing`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_missing) and reloaded when they change. Take a look here at the [Rails initialization process](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check method [`autoload`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload), whose planned deprecation [has been halted for now](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5653), and also [`const_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-const_missing), to name just two. Another available mechanism would be eg. to rescue `NameError` exceptions for uninitialized constants...